# Qt application crashes on quit event on Mac OSX

Tags: qt, macos

I'm just starting out with Qt on a Mac and working through:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/gettingstartedqt.html

When I run the second example which has the following code:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argv, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argv, args);

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    QPushButton quitButton("Quit");

    QObject::connect(&quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout layout;
    layout.addWidget(&textEdit);
    layout.addWidget(&quitButton);

    QWidget window;
    window.setLayout(&layout);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The application starts up fine and works fine. The only issue occurs when I click the "Quit" button. When I do that the crash reporter is invoked and osx says the app quit unexpectedly.

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the order of the delete if you declare variables on the stack. The best it to give your object parents so that they can destroy the children.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    // If window get's destroyed, it will destroy it's children...
    QTextEdit textEdit(&window);
    QPushButton quitButton("Quit",&window);

    QObject::connect(&quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout layout;
    layout.addWidget(&textEdit);
    layout.addWidget(&quitButton);

    window.setLayout(&layout);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

PS: Did you actually try a debugger to see where it crashes? It will give you an idea ;) My suggestion is to take a working Qt example and play with it.

PS2: The order I created the widgets also prevents the crash...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
QTextEdit * textEdit = new QTextEdit;
QPushButton * quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit");
```